# How many hosts are in the following IP?

Tags: subnet, ip

Honestly, I just know some basics about subnetting and hosts, but how can you determine how many hosts would be in the following IP 10.10.0.0/22?

Comment: Since there are 32 bits in an address, you can easily calculate the number of host bits because you are given the number of network bits.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thank you. How exactly would that be calculated?

Comment: Simple subtraction gives you the number of host bits.

Comment: @MikePennington I appreciate you sharing that thread. Very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for any host x.x.x.x/n

you have 32 - n bits available

which means

2^(32 - n)

but one of these needs to be a broadcast ip and one of them needs to be a netowrk ip, so

2^(32 - n) - 2

for your specific question

/22 = 2^10 - 2 = 1022